# Forward declaration with reference-counting smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, forward-declaration, type-erasure

I have implemented a class `reference<T>` that keeps track of the amount of references to a `T` which derives from `reference_countable`.

I have a problem with it with respect to forward declaring the `T` of the `reference<T>`, similar to that of `std::unique_ptr<T>`. With `std::unique_ptr<T>` the issue comes from the destructor not beeing known, so all you have to do is put the destructor of your class into the cpp file, like so:

header:

```cpp
class MyClass;
class A
{
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> my_class;
}
```

implementation:

```cpp
A:~A() = default;
```

However, in my version, where `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>` is replaced by `reference<MyClass>`, the `reference_countable` must also be decremented and incremented. Which requires me to also put the copy-assignment and copy-constructor of `A` in cpp file when `MyClass` is only forward declared.

Is there a way to avoid having to put the implementation for these three functions in the cpp file for all classes with a `reference<T>` member?

---

I've tried to describe it as simple as I can, but for more detail, here is a simple version of the problem. Specifically, the need to define the copy-constructor of `A` in a.cpp.

my_class.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "minimal_ref_counter.h"

class MyClass : public minimal_reference_countable
{
};
```

a.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "minimal_ref_counter.h"

class MyClass;

class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    A(const A&);
    minimal_reference_counter<MyClass> my_class;
};
```

a.cpp

```cpp
#include "test.h"
#include "myclass.h"

A::A() 
    : my_class(new MyClass())
{}

A::~A() = default;

A::A(const A&) = default;
```

some_other_code.cpp

```cpp
#include "a.h"

void some_function()
{
    A a1;
    A a2 = a1; // this code does not compile without the copy assignment operator beeing implemented externally.
}
```

minimal_ref_counter.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <atomic>

class minimal_reference_countable
{
    template<typename T>
    friend class minimal_reference_counter;

    std::atomic_int m_references = 0;

    auto reference_count() const { return m_references.load(); }

    void decrement() { --m_references; }
    void increment() { ++m_references; }
};

template<typename T>
class minimal_reference_counter
{
public:

    minimal_reference_counter(T* t = nullptr)
    {
        assign(t);
    }

    ~minimal_reference_counter()
    {
        reset();
    }

    minimal_reference_counter(const minimal_reference_counter& r)
    {
        *this = r;
    }

    minimal_reference_counter(minimal_reference_counter&& r)
    {
        *this = std::move(r);
    }

    minimal_reference_counter& operator=(const minimal_reference_counter& r)
    {
        assign(r.m_ptr);
        return *this;
    }

    minimal_reference_counter& operator=(minimal_reference_counter&& r)
    {
        assign(r.m_ptr);
        r.reset();
        return *this;
    }

    void reset()
    {
        if (!m_ptr) return;
        m_ptr->decrement();
        if (m_ptr->reference_count() == 0) 
        {
            delete m_ptr;
        }
        m_ptr = nullptr;
    }

private:

    void assign(T* ptr)
    {
        reset();
        m_ptr = ptr;
        if (m_ptr) m_ptr->increment();
    }

    T* m_ptr = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: I'm more curious about why you need to create this `reference<T>` class? What problem does it solve that `std::shared_ptr<T>` doesn't solve?

Comment: you misunderstood why the destructor goes in the cpp file: it's just to defer instantiating `std::unique_ptr::~unique_ptr` (or really `std::default_delete::operator()`) until after `MyClass::~MyClass` is visible

Comment: However, if you have a `reference_countable` base class, you don't need to know anything about the derived `MyClass` to use it. Why not just store a base class pointer and handle downcasting in `operator*` or whatever?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The goal is to have a more light-weight version of shared_ptr 
 (that might even have a non-thread-safe version).

Comment: @Useless The forward `MyClass` is not known to have the `reference_countable`  base class. So the increment in decrement can not be called. I'd have to store 2 pointers, on to `MyClass` and one to `reference_countable` which I'd rather not do, when the only goal is not having to put the copy assignment/constructor in the cpp file.

Comment: Have you measured the overhead of atomics in `std::shared_ptr`, and found it too much?

Comment: You need a more complete example. This is too much guess work at what your actual code looks like. Have a look at how to make a [mcve].

Comment: @super
I've tried to add code to reduce the guess work.

Comment: @Caleth outside of the performance, I am also interested from a learning perspective if and how this could be done.

Comment: You're the one who said your stored types used the `reference_countable` base. However, it's reasonable to just use duck-typing instead (ie, it should work for any type with suitable `increment` and `decrement` methods).

Answer (score 1):

C++ templates are lazy. Instantiations are deferred until necessary. The reason to put the destructor in the cpp file when you have a member `std::unique_ptr` of an incomplete type, later completed, is that the destructor needs the destructor of `unique_ptr`, thus instantiating it, which needs the destructor of the pointed-to type which requires that type to be complete. This chain of dependencies triggered by the definition of the destructor must be deferred until such time as the pointed-to type is complete.

In your reference counted pointer case, you wonder if the copy constructor, copy assignment operator, and destructor of the pointer necessarily require completeness of the pointed-to type, and likewise their instantiations be deferred until such time as the pointed to type is complete.

Because the pointer destructor potentially invokes the destructor of the pointed-to type, that type *necessarily* must be complete when the pointer destructor is instantiated.  This is similar to `unique_ptr` and so should be unsurprising.

Similarly, the pointer copy assignment potentially invokes the destructor of the pointed-to type. It replaces the pointee with another pointee and decrements the original pointee's reference count and destroys it if necessary. So, for the same reason as the destructor, the pointer copy assignment operator requires the pointed-to type *necessarily* be complete when it is instantiated.

The copy constructor is more subtle. No potential destructions of the pointed-to type are invoked. However, with this implementation, we act on a base class of the pointed-to type to increment the reference count. This requires completeness, as otherwise there are no base classes. So, with this implementation, yes, the poitned-to type *necessarily* must be complete when the copy constructor is instantiated.

There are alternative implementations, of course. One could keep both a `T*` and a `minimal_reference_counter<T>*`, instead of finding the latter from the former as a base class. `shared_ptr` does this. In fact, one could also store the destructor as a function pointer and not require the other awkward instantiation deferrals. `shared_ptr` does this too.